# Apply Validation in angular 4.0 textbox control

Tags: jquery, angular, validation, typescript, textbox

I am having a component named numeric textbox i have to apply a validation of required filed  time of button click 
here is my component.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'numeric',
    templateUrl: './numeric.template.html'
})
```

and here is my control.

```
<input type="number" id="{{id}}"  [(ngModel)]="NumericVal" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" value="NumericVal" />{{NumericVal}}
```

validation means when i click on a button then a css is appiled over text box in red color. 
So can this done?
I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: checkout https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the simplest is

```
<input 
  type="number"
  [id]="id"
  [(ngModel)]="NumericVal"
  [class.required]="!NumericVal"
  [min]="min" [max]="max" />
```

But I would advise using reactive forms. Since you don't use them and are not asking for help on it, I will let you read the documentation on that.

Comment: how to apply that class !NumericalVal

Comment: This is not a class, that's a condition. Do you know how inputs work in Angular ? Because if you don't, it's time to browse the doc again !

Comment: I  know about inputs in angular but can we access it on component file using 
@Input class.required

Comment: So you don't know :) look at the documentation for ngClass, you'll understand this particular input !